# Error de escritura de un archivo en disco al generar un reporte en django después de migrar la base de datos oracle desde la versión 11 a la 19c

Tags: django, oracle, apache

Buen día,

Se tiene una aplicación web en django apuntando a una base de datos oracle y se corre con apache 2.4 en windows server 2012. La base de datos se migró de la version 11 a la 19c.

Los reportes se solicitan desde la pagina web, invocando una funcionalidad de una aplicación de terceros (ORA_EXCEL) que se ejecuta directamente en el servidor de base de datos y el archivo queda en una carpeta compartida entre el servidor de base de datos y el servidor web

En el momento de migrarse a la version 19c los reportes ya no se pueden generar por el siguiente error:

```
ORA-20100: Procedure save_to_file -20100 
ORA-20100: Procedure blob_to_file-29283 
ORA-29283: invalid file operation: unexpected "LFI" error (1509)[29437] 
ORA-06512: at "ORA_EXCEL", line 3994 
ORA-06512: at line 1 )
```

El error se debe a que Oracle 19c ya no permite vínculos simbólicos, se busca otra solución.

Se ha intentado configurar el servidor apache adicionando el parametro `FollowSymLinks`, pero no funciona

```
<Directory "D:/Apache24/htdocs">
Require all granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/REPORTES-DB">
Require all granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>
```

Nota: En el mismo servidor se tiene una aplicación jsp en Tomcat y la solución para habilitar los vínculos simbólicos fué agregar allowLinking="true" en el archivo context.xml de la carpeta META-INF

Si es posible alguien me pueda dar alguna sugerencia de como corregir el error, estaría muy agradecido

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Cuando dices carpeta compartida, es una unidad de red windows o cómo la compartes? La cosa es que eso no es visible en tu pregunta y hay que darle permisos al usuario que corre el servicio del proceso Oracle. Recuerda que puedes responder a las preguntas en los comentarios yendo a [edit] la pregunta cuantas veces quieras.

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto configuración final para que funcionara el descargue del archivo generándolo desde el servidor de base de datos https://youtu.be/5-J8FCgrID0

Comment: Recuerda que el contenido esencial debe ir _en la respuesta_. Piénsalo: si alguien llega a tener un problema similar, y el enlace está roto: ¿cuál entonces será la respuesta? Lee [answer].